# Executable console group on Windows using PowerShell Remoting

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, console

I have a Windows application that generates the following (cryptic) error when I try to run via PowerShell Remoting or [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) (same result).

> Could not locate executable console group for user/process

I'm not totally sure what this means, but playing around with low-level process creation functionality hasn't really panned out:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8762068/647151

  This doesn't support the setting of *creationflags*, but does return output of the process.
- https://github.com/FuzzySecurity/PowerShell-Suite/blob/master/Invoke-CreateProcess.ps1

  This does support the setting of *creationflags* and it seems that `DETACHED_PROCESS` might do the trick, but I am not sure how to get any process output.

It probably doesn't make a difference but the "user" here is a [group-managed service account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview).

What precisely might this cryptic error message mean and is there a way to ... work around it somehow. I'm basically just trying to run the application via PowerShell Remoting (it is a data batch-processing program).

The operating system is Windows Server 2012 with PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: What the exact **Windows Version** you're trying to run that application? Please, add to your post and tags too.

Comment: How large is the exe and it is just an exe with no other dependencies? Is the cryptic error message too large or sensitive to share? Does this exe have this issue with the managed service account if you run it on the machine locally? How do you reference the remote code for the part that executes the exe? Is the exe you are executing sitting on a remote share somewhere or the local path on the remove machine it is executed on remotely?

Comment: The executable is CADISProcessAgent.exe – a commercial software now sold under the name IHS Markit: https://ihsmarkit.com/products/cadis.html. It's a local console-like program.